# Prove that the limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that the limit does not exist for the following function:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (2,1)}\frac{4y^2-x^2}{(x-2y)^3}$$

I tried taking different paths for the limit, but I couldn't get anywhere with that.
Now I want to try proving it with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many "different paths" you *checked*??

$$y=mx+(1-2m)\implies \frac{4(mx+(1-2m))^2-x^2}{(x-(2mx+2-4m)^3}=$$

$$=\frac{\color{red}{\left[2(mx+1-2m)-x\right]}\left[2(mx+1-2m)+x\right]}{\color{red}{(x-2(mx+1-2m))^3}}=$$

$$=-\frac{2(mx+1-2m)+x)}{(x-2(mx+1-2m))^2}\xrightarrow[x\to 2]{}\;\text{doesn't exist finitely}$$

and thus the limit cannot exist...

Comment: The point is $(2,1)$ not $(0,0)$. $y=mx$ does not pass through $(2,1)$ except for $m=1/2$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal buuuuut along $m=\frac12$ limit does not exist. Done.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: Try to see my point.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal no I see your point very well. I am just saying with one extra line, the proof works. The limit doesn't exist along $y=\frac{x}{2}$ so we are done. Although your proof is cleaner.

Comment: Guys, this was a 10 mark question in my mid term exam. I don't think just stating that the limit doesn't exist along y = x/2 would be enough. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal is right, I missed that one. Thanks. I shall edit accordingly though I think the "bug" is easily mendable.

Comment: Well @SighMath, choosing $\;y=\frac12x\;$ seems to be pretty intuitive as it is the straight line (almost easiet possible function) through the origin...

Comment: @SighMath, check the answer now...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$ (4y^2-x^2)=(2y-x)(2y+x) $$

Comment: Yes, I got to this part, but I dont know what to do beyond this!

Comment: @SighMath $(x-2y)^3 = (x-2y)(x^2 +2xy+4y^2)$

Comment: And then I'm left with $\frac{2y+x}{(x-2y)^2}$ Then what!

Comment: What do you mean "then what", @SighMath? At the limit the denominator vanishes whereas the numerator doesn't and thus the limit doesn't exist finitely!