# Show the limit of $f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question. 
The question is this : Show that the function $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)}f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ does not exist.
My solution is this :

1. $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x, 0) = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^2}{x} = 0$
2. $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(0, y) = \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{y}{y} = 1$

By showing there are two different limits, the function does not have limit.
Can I do this??

Comment: you can, except notice that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ and not necessarily $x$ but this can be easily sorted out

Comment: yes, you can do that. Although, the limit for part 2 is $\frac{y}{|y|} = \pm 1$ depending on the way you approach the origin with respect to $y$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the limit does not exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714187/prove-that-the-limit-does-not-exist)